# rewrite url remove prefix and proxy pass

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I need to stripe down a url prefix and proxy_pass it with a re-write rule

http://xxx/v5_5_5/api/login/test
http://xxx/v4_4_4/api/login/test
http://xxx/v3_3_3/api/login/test

to

http://xxx/api/logint/test

I've tried using multiple regex patterns and rewrite methods but i can't get it to work with proxy pass, the critical thing here is that i want this to be performed server side, i don't want the client to experience a 301/302 redirect...

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
location ~ ^/v._._./(.*) {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://xxx/$1;
}
```

~ for regex

^ begin of line

. means any char

(.*) captures anything inside $1

and you proxy pass to http://xxx/$1

Does this work for your exact case?